# KeyNotFoundException in DynamicJson

Tags: rally

Using the create defect example from the .NET toolkit page [here](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/rest-api-net).

I get the following error when trying to use the DynamicJsonObject -

toCreate["Name"] 'toCreate["Name"]' threw an exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' dynamic {System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException}

The code I am using is just as the example states:

```
 DynamicJsonObject toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
        toCreate["Name"] = "My Defect";

        CreateResult createResult = restApi.Create(workspaceRef, "defect", toCreate);
```

Is this a problem on my end or is there a defect in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the full example that works. When we create a defect:

```
CreateResult createResult = restApi.Create(workspaceRef, "defect", myDefect);
```

and immediately try to print its FormattedID:

```
Console.WriteLine(myDefect["FormattedID"]);
```

the same System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException is generated. Is it possible you have something similar in your code?

On the other hand, if we create a defect, and then get by reference,we can print the FormattedID, and there is no KeyNotFoundException:

```
DynamicJsonObject d = restApi.GetByReference(createResult.Reference, "FormattedID");
Console.WriteLine(d["FormattedID"]);
```

Here is the code. I made some changes to the example. Delete requires workspace reference parameter.
Since in the end the defect is deleted, you may find it in the recycle bin.

```
namespace CreateDefectFromExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Initialize the REST API
            RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi("user@co.com", "TopSecret1984", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "1.40");
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/111111111";     //use your workspace OID
            //Create an item
            DynamicJsonObject myDefect = new DynamicJsonObject();
            myDefect["Name"] = "worst defect ever";
            CreateResult createResult = restApi.Create(workspaceRef, "defect", myDefect);
            //Console.WriteLine(myDefect["FormattedID"]); //this line causes System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
            DynamicJsonObject d = restApi.GetByReference(createResult.Reference, "FormattedID");
            Console.WriteLine(d["FormattedID"]);


            //Update the item DynamicJsonObject toUpdate = new DynamicJsonObject();
            myDefect["Description"] = "This is my defect.";
            OperationResult updateResult = restApi.Update(createResult.Reference, myDefect);

            //Get the item
            DynamicJsonObject item = restApi.GetByReference(createResult.Reference, "Name");
            string name = item["Name"];

            //Query for items
            Request request = new Request("defect");
            request.Fetch = new List<string>()
    {
    "Name",
    "Description",
    "FormattedID"
     };
            request.Query = new Query("Name", Query.Operator.Equals, "My Defect");
            QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request);
            foreach (var result in queryResult.Results)
            {
                //Process item
                string formattedID = result["FormattedID"];

            }
            //Delete the item
            OperationResult deleteResult = restApi.Delete(workspaceRef, createResult.Reference);
        }

    }
}
```